# Find the most used property value in a table entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a table which each row has property named `CompanyId` and I need to find the `CompanyId` which has been mostly used in the table.

example :

```
[id = 1 , CompanyID = 23]
[id = 2 , CompanyID = 10]
[id = 3 , CompanyID = 10]
[id = 4 , CompanyID = 11]
[id = 5 , CompanyID = 23]
[id = 6 , CompanyID = 23]
[id = 7 , CompanyID = 23]
```

How can I find 23 in the table ?

```
var mostUsedCompanyId = _context ...
```

Comment: Groupby and count then orderby

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var mostUsedCompanyId =
    _content
        .Entities
        .GroupBy(it => it.CompanyId).OrderByDescending(it => it.Count())
        .First()
        .CompanyId;
```